# SQLplus script to format text as numeric

Tags: formatting, sqlplus, scripting

I am selecting rows from a table, but some of the columns are a text type, but they always have numeric data in them.  How can I format them as numbers?

e.g. column quantity heading 'Quantity' format 999,999

However, since the column in the table is text, the numeric formatting is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to TO_NUMBER the column in your query.

Answer (score 1):

To render with thousand seperators, you'll need to...

```
to_char(to_number(quantity), '999,999')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve,

I can now have:

```
column quantity heading 'Quantity' format 999,999
select TO_NUMBER(quantity) as quantity from Sales
```

And I get a right justified report.